# Is it ok to update the value of a field of a database very often by assigning `value(field) = value(field) + 1`?

Tags: mysql

When the probability of data loss of value(field) in 1 update (or simple in some time passing) is more than 0, then it is sure that on some point in future, the data is lost.

But how relevant is this theoretical conclusion in practice?

I need to have a database that stores the "user-likes" of a certain thing by a database design `ID | THING | LIKES(int)`. Additionally to that there will be a database storing every single like of a user in a design `ID | USER | THING`.

When the amount of likes of a certain `THING` has to be displayed, it would be too slow to count every row of the second database `WHERE THING = $value` so I would just look up `LIKES`of the first database and if the user likes a thing I would just increase the number of `LIKES` by 1 (as in the theoretical question above).

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't worry about writing data from an "false-values" point of view. Most databases I know of guarantee the [ACID-Properties](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID%22ACID-Properties).
Counting of course is slower than already having the count available to access via a key-index.